# React (jest) + vscode Debug Console "screen.debug is not a function"

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, vitest

**Using vscode debug console**, debugging a jest/vitest test, trying to call `screen.debug(<Element>)`, I get the following error:

[image]

How can I use this function **in the Debug Console of Vscode**?